# Method for matching URLs in text

Tags: php

In PHP, what is the recommended method for matching all URLs in a body of text (ie, a form $_POST textarea as opposed to a one 'word' string) please?

I am looking for a method which matches the large majority of URLs, not a super standards-compliant catch-all. Examples that I like to match:

- http://www.google.com
- http://google.com
- www.google.com
- google.com
- any of the above with various query data (ie /?foo=bar)

Ideally the result(s) would be put into an associative array.

I understand that parse_url is not well suited. And I've heard that using a regex is fraught with problems. Yet I've also heard that filter_var has significant issues, not the least of which is that a scheme is required. What technique do you all use?

Thank you

Comment: Regex should be proper for that. However, "google.com" could lead to many false positives. You should consider to match against a list of valid TLDs.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would think testing against multiple regexs is the way to go.

Here are some example regexs that should match www.google.com:

- `/^google[.]com/`
- `/^http:\/\/www[.]google[.]com/`

Answer (score 0):

it will extract all above urls in text.

```
<?php

$string='http://www.google.com?q=1000
http://google.com?xlkd=0
www.google.com?asdfsdf=asdf
google.com?234324';


preg_match_all('#\b(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)??[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
```

output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.google.com?q=1000
            [1] => http://google.com?xlkd=0
            [2] => www.google.com?asdfsdf=asdf
            [3] => google.com?234324
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => f
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

Hope it will helpful

Comment: Thank you, this is a good start, but this also seems to match non-url text.

Comment: in the second item of the multidimensional, yes, but it seems you can only use `$match[0]`